# One way Repeated measure ANOVA with CATEGORICAL response

Tags: repeated-measures, ordinal-data

I am analyzing a data where the response is collected at 3-time points, however, the response is ordinal with 3 categories: low, medium, and high. In, addition, I also have some covariates I would like to control for to see if there is a change in the response over time. Unfortunately, I do not seem to find an analysis that I can conduct with the categorical repeated response. Can anybody suggest an appropriate analysis for my problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your response variable as a numeric, re-code it if it's not a numeric value to 1, 2 and 3. Since in your context, low is less than Medium and medium is less than high. then you can choose the appropriate method

Comment: Any idea what that appropriate method might be? This is where I am struggling.

Comment: There's very little information on your data, varibles and what you are trying to do-  in order to receive answers you need to include a sample of your data and clearly state what question you are trying to answer.